# Test to compare difference in location estimates between sex

Tags: r

I have geolocation data for the wintering locations of ~20 birds. I want to know if there is a sex-specific difference between male and female wintering grounds.

[Geolocation data is very broad scale i.e.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv8ql.png)

This is for R gui. I have tried very simple tests (wilcoxs) which suggests there is a difference, but these only account for longitude (x), not both longitude and latitude (y)

Any advice on which package/function would be most appropriate to use to further determine if there is a difference? Pinpoint analysis (Spatstat) was suggested but I'm unsure my data qualifies for its use due to broad resolution of geodata. Likewise was ade4 to find a home range estimate then compare the centroids, however I have a small sample size (only 5 females) so this appears to not be possible, in addition I am not interested in range, merely difference in distribution.

Comment: Please add some code samples.

Comment: Maybe more suitable for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programing problem indeed, you should visit **stackexchange**.

Here you have some information.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48754/learning-spatial-statistics/48764